# How to get dynamic textbox value c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a button that generate some textboxes, but I don't know how to get the respective textboxes values.
I found some similar idea only using asp.net c#, but I think that's a bit different.
This is my code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int control = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.Top = control * 25;
            txt.Left = 100;
            txt.Name = "TextBox" + this.control.ToString();
            control = control + 1;
        }
```

Can someone help me?!

Comment: You need to store the constructed `TextBox` objects somewhere.  You're letting the `txt` variable to just fall out of scope.  You _could_ iterate over `this.Controls` and look for unique control names too.  Far from ideal though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've added the Text boxes to `this.Controls` so you can go rummaging in there to find them again

```
foreach(var c in this.Controls){
  if(c is TextBox t && t.Name.StartsWith("TextBox"))
    MessageBox.Show(t.Text);
```

I'd pick better names for Name than "TextBox"+integer but  so long as you don't name other text boxes that you don't want to consider with the same prefix this will pick up only those you added dynamically

If you know the controls by name I,e, you know that you want the address and that the user has certainly typed it into TextBox 2, you can just access Controls indexed by that name:

```
this.Controls["TextBox2"].Text;
```

Doesn't even need casting to a TextBox.. all Controls have a text property

Comment: I did put the textboxes in a panel and then used the foreach. It worked! ```foreach (TextBox txtb in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {"Then I got the values"}```. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, it would be important to note that by default doing a `foreach(var c in this.Controls)` will NOT recursively travel into a panel.. The panel itself would be one of the controls that appeared as you enumerate `this.Controls`, but not anything inside it. You'd need to say `foreach(var c in thePanel.Controls)`... I used `this.Controls` because you did in your question. Always make sure to post the *actual* code you're using, not some different representation of  it, unless you're absolutely sure you can translate any answers you receive back along the same process to get something that works

Answer (score 1):

When you have the instance of the textbox, you can get the value by reading the Value property. One way to get the instance is to search it the Controls list, when you give the texbox a unique name.

```
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.Name = "UniqueName";
    Controls.Add(txt);
}

{
    foreach(var control in Controls)
       if (control is TextBox tb && tb.Name == "UniqueName")
         return tb.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [Control.ControlCollection.Find(String, Boolean) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_) to get the textbox you want.

```
string text = ((TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textboxname", true)[0]).Text;
```